# My Dell laptop fan is not spinning

Tags: dual-boot, 22.04, dell, fan, overheating

I have dual-booted my Dell laptop. Now I have Windows 11 and Ubuntu. My problem is my fan is not spinning in my Ubuntu OS. But it spins when I at my windows OS. That is why When I worked on my Ubuntu OS my laptop started heating up. I checked it using I8kmon fan shows me the result -1 -1. { MY laptop model is - Dell Inspiron 14 2-in-1 (intel) }